# How to draw vertical line at the given pixel of a div

Tags: html, css

Drawing a vertical line with **border-left** and **border-right** seems easy.

But in my case I am having a single div and I need to draw a vertical line at the given pixel
say **(240px)**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what do mean by single div?

Comment: you means you want to draw that vertical line 240px away from that div ??

Comment: a div for 100% width and some how 20% height. Ex: navbar

Comment: @BhaveshGangani 240px from the start of the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `:after` or `:before` pseudo element for this, and position it `absolute` at 240px.

*Example*: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/YMS4F/1/**

*CSS*:

```
div.split {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div.split:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 240px;
}
```

Taken, width and height in pixels for demo purpose. Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create another div within the main div and give that border-left/border-right and then you can scale the inner div to what you want and also higher or lower it.

Just edit the code to suit your needs

HTML

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="child"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background:silver;
}

.child {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:1px;
    background:red;
    top:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Qj2d/